# how to print a value that I stored in a variable in a class?

Tags: c#, class, methods, printing, int

I have a class and  method that fills this class's value:

```
class Dice
{
    public int value;
    static Random rnd = new Random();


    public void Throw()
    {

        Dice dice;
        dice = new Dice();
        dice.value = rnd.Next(1, 7);

    }
```

Finally I just want to print dice.value after it has been already filled with a random number.
I thought I can make something like.

```
 public void DisplayValue()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(value);

    }
```

but this is only printing 0, can someone tell me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you didn't fill your Dice !!

rewrite your `Throw` function to this:

```
public void Throw()
{
    this.value = rnd.Next(1, 7);
}
```

You are trying to create a temporary `Dice` object and assigning some value to it.

Comment: Thanks I am new to this indeed so you don't need roast me indirectly with multiple exclamation marks. :P
Thanks for your help though